# passing json formatted with information from multiple json documents nodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a function where I would like to return an arrays of JSON objects with the necessary information. to send directly to the front everything ready.

```
async listProcessByOffice(req, res, next) {
try {
  const actualPlayer = await PlayerOffice.findById(req.userId);
  const actualOffice = await Office.findById(actualPlayer.Office);
  const listProcesses = await Processes.find({ '_id': { $in: actualOffice.processes } });
  const infosTable = {
    protocol: ''
  };
  for (let i in listProcesses) {
    this.protocol = listProcesses[i].prc_protocol;
    console.log(this.protocol)
  }
  return res.status(200).json({ infosTable });
} catch (err) {
  return next(err);
}
```

Comment: Please include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are looking for but i am assuming that you want to response back with array list of objects. So simple answer will be,

```
const infosTable = [];

 for (let i in listProcesses) {
    this.protocol = listProcesses[i].prc_protocol;
    infosTable.push({protocol:listProcesses[i].prc_protocol})
    console.log(this.protocol)
  }
```